# How to prevent direct access to pages from url for jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a web application. Everything works fine.But, if the user is not logged in still they can have access to other jsp pages through url. I want to stop url access. I saw some example it shows the usage of filters. I'm new to filters I don't how to implement it. I'm using servlets, dao and jsp pages.

Please suggests me how to do it. I want to make one filter for all the jsp or servlets pages.

```
Web.XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MBO</display-name>
   <filter>
  <filter-name>MyFiltersDAO</filter-name>
  <filter-class>Model.MyFiltersDAO</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>MyFiltersDAO</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/secret/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

Class :

```
public class MyFiltersDAO {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

         HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            String abc=(String) req.getSession().getAttribute("Username");
            if(null==((String) req.getSession().getAttribute("Username")) || ((String) req.getSession().getAttribute("Username")).equals("")){
                chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        } else {
          resp.sendRedirect("/Login.jsp");
      }
    }


    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

when i run project it shows HTTP404 error

Comment: have you tried using a session?

Comment: This link can be use full for you : https://www.javatpoint.com/authentication-filter

Comment: You might have a look at Spring Security, even if you're not using Spring (and you really shouldn't be hand-coding servlets when useful frameworks are available).

Comment: Put jsp files into web-inf folder so user can't access it directly. And use HttpSession to store logged in user

Comment: I had the same issue. I used the code in this link under "disable direct access of jsp page - JavaServer Pages (JSP) and JSTL": https://java.databasedevelop.com/article/11412792/disable+direct+access+of+jsp+page (see the code added to the web.xml file). This works for me perfectly. Only if a person clicks on a link, the user can access the page, but if the user puts the .jsp page in the url, the user will not have access, and it will throw a "HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden" error, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

you can give a try to session.Suppose when a user logs in then you can set a session attribute in session like

```
   if(loggedIn)
{
session.setAttribute("username",username);
}
```

and in your jsp you can validate when the page loads that if session is not null only then that page should be accessed else redirect user to home page

```
if(session.getAttribute("username")!=null)
{


}
else
{
response.sendredirect(url)
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You can do it using

```
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
  if(loggedIn)
    {
    session.setAttribute("username",user))
response.sendredirect("index.jsp");
    }
}
```

in your index.jsp

```
<%

if (session.getAttribute("username") !=null) {
//your code
}
else
{
//your code
}
%>
```

Comment: Hi, how can I call this class from servlet

Comment: in your servlet httpresponse object is alreay created by default in get and post methods,you just need to make a session object like    Httpsession session=response.getSession(); And then set session as session.setAttribute(arg1,arg2),   in your jsp you can directly use session.getAttribute(arg1) inside a scriplet

Comment: Hi,@Vikram Saini, can u please provide me  code for this  I am newer to this Java  please help me out

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I did without login pages not accessing It redirect to login page but when I login with user name and password it not open next page where did I do mistake can u please tell me

Comment: then may be your credentials are not getting validated properly.you can debug your code and check if username and password are actually matching for that particular user or not.If credentials are validated then after that you can write response.sendredirect("login.jsp").May be you are missing it

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi,@Vikram Saini,[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647044/when-i-access-pages-without-login-it-works-fine-but-when-i-login-page-is-not-dis. I raised another question could you please see that link. Here i changed my code `String loginURI = req.getContextPath() + "/Login.jsp";
         boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("Username") != null;
            boolean loginRequest = req.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);            
         if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);} else {resp.sendRedirect(loginURI); }`