# When I access Pages without login it works fine but when i login page is not displaying not working

Tags: java, jsp

by using `filters` concept i need to gave security to without accessing pages through url but when i access the login page with credentials login page is not displaying properly. I'm using servlets, dao and jsp pages.

Please suggests me how to do it.

```
Web.XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MBO</display-name>
   <filter>
  <filter-name>MyFiltersDAO</filter-name>
  <filter-class>Model.MyFiltersDAO</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>MyFiltersDAO</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

Class :

```
 @WebFilter("/*")
public class MyFiltersDAO implements Filter{
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

         HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
            String loginURI = req.getContextPath() + "/Login.jsp";
            boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("Username") != null;
            boolean loginRequest = req.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);            


            if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                resp.sendRedirect(loginURI);
            }           
    }           

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

When i access pages without login it works fine but when i run with credentials to access pages it shows at the url login.jsp page html code and page isn't working

Comment: Hey you should not use @WebFilter("/*") if you are configuring the filter in web.xml. either use @WebFilter or web.xml configuration.

Comment: I think it will solve your issue if you use one of its configuration

Comment: Hi, @Mayur, can you please tell me how can I do this

Comment: remove the filter configuration from web.xml and try because you already have marked your filter by annotation @WebFilter

Comment: can i remove this `@WebFilter("/*")` from `MYFilter page` u r saying about this

Comment: @Mayur, It's not working it display when i need to with valid credentials  login it shows `http://localhost:8080/MBO/Login.jsp#btnLogin').click(function ()            {                            $.ajax({                    type: "post",                    url: "Login", //this is my servlet                    data: "uname=" +$('#inputUserID').val()+"&pwd="+$('#inputPassword').val(),                    success: f` and it not displaying page

Comment: Please find this example it may help you http://www.concretepage.com/java-ee/jsp-servlet/how-to-use-filter-in-servlet-3-with-webfilter-annotation